# How to separate the file name and the extension of a file in c#

Tags: c#, filenames, file-extension

Is it possible to separate the name of the file to it's file type/ file extension.

For example I have this file named sample.text. I want to get separate sample and .txt using c#.

Can anyone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var extension = 
    Path.GetExtension("C:\\sample.txt"); // returns txt
```

..and [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var fileNameWithoutExtension = 
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("C:\\sample.txt"); // returns sample
```